# Google map suddenly not showing

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My site is using the Google Maps Geocode API and every now and then the map on my website doesn't display. For example, yesterday morning it showed just fine but sometime in the afternoon the site just showed a blank area where the map should be. I was also getting a JS error that said "google is not defined" and was in reference to new google.maps.LatLng. This morning it was still blank and then a about an hour later it was working again.

So as far as I can tell, the map was showing blank for at least 18 hours. Could the site have reached some kind of usage limit that caused Google to temporarily disallow access to the maps API for the site? Or was it just something on Google's side that was down for a bit?

I've been browsing around for an answer to this in order to hopefully avoid the same issue from happening again in the future but haven't found anything concrete yet. I do see that Google has a usage limit of 2500 loads per day for the free version, which is what I have but it says your site has to hit that limit for 90 consecutive days. I don't think my site has hit that limit for that long but that was really the only thing I found that seemed like a possible reason for it going down.

Does anyone know more about the Google API to help me understand the possible causes of the map not displaying sometimes? I visited the Google API site first and it referenced Stack Overflow so I thought I'd see if anyone could offer some insight.

Thanks.

Comment: You get `google is not defined` message when google api is not loaded. I saw that sometimes when there was a problem with a link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "google is not defined" while using Gmap3. The problem was that I was including 'gmap3' before including 'google', so I reversed the order:

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  <script src="/assets/gmap3.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are not causing "Mixed Content" error, by loading google maps script via http from https.